# how to pass NSString value to connectionDidFinishLoading

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have Json url.i Know to get data for JSON url.but now i have one issue.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"index number %d", indexPath.row);
    passingDealDec=[titleDecarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"passingDealDec%@",passingDealDec);
    // you can see selected row number in your console;
}
```

I need  passingDealDec(NSString) pass to connectionDidFinishLoading method i tried like this but it's not work

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
if ([getDealsDec isEqualToString:passingDealDec]){
            NSLog(@"firstpassingDealDec%@",passingDealDec);
            NSString *geting2 =[diction valueForKey:@"dealimage"];
            NSData *getdata2=[[NSData alloc]initWithData:[NSData dataFromBase64String:geting2]];
            NSLog(@"good day2 %@",getdata2);
            UIImage   *singleimage=[UIImage imageWithData:getdata2];

            NSLog(@"GetingSingleImage%@",singleimage);

            //[imagesarray addObject:singleimage];

            NSString  *Dealtitles =[dealPosted valueForKey:@"deaTitle"];
            NSLog(@"Singletitles^^^%@",Dealtitles);

            NSString *DealPrice=[dealPosted valueForKey:@"price"];
            NSLog(@"DealPrice^^^DealPrice%@",DealPrice);
        }
}
```

Please tell me what wrong in my code.First tell me after didSelectRowAtIndexPath method call to connectionDidFinishLoading.It's possible or not.

Thanks in Advanced .

Comment: from where you call the url?

Comment: @BHASKAR i call the url in viewDidLoad

Comment: so when you tap the tableview passingDealDec is nil

Comment: getDealsDec and passingDealDec must be declared as class properties to access everywhere

Answer (score 0):

If you know ConnectionDidFinishLoading is firing after didSelectAtIndexPath 
Then declare DealDec as a global (instance) variable, so setting the variable to the value in the didSelectAtIndexPath, and the value will remain as it was set and you can access it in the Later function.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
 NSString *DealDec;
}
```

P.S- If you dont know which method is fired before, put two breakpoints in each method, run the app and watch which one gets executed first.

Hope this helps

[EDIT]

```
didSelectIndexPath{
NSURLConnection *myURL;
 Cell.myLabel.text = myURL; //taking that some label text in the cell class has a URl and u want to fire it when u click on it.
[self.connectionDidFinishLoading:myURL]; 
}
```

This would solve the issue

Comment: thanks for Reply first call ConnectionDidFinishLoading and then when i press UITableViewCell call to DidselectAtIndexPath but now i need to after didselectIndexpath my String value pass to ConnectionDidFinishLoading Please help me it's possible or not .If it's possible Please help

Comment: is ConnectionDidFinishLoading a custom method?

Comment: No -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

Comment: Ok, its a URLDelegateMethod, so if your application is some webbased application then probably ConnectionDidFinishLoading is called before,
then when u select any tableview component, then your didSelectAtIndexPath is fired. 

If your didSelectIndexPath, method returns a link, then you have to return the value and call that method, check the EDIT

Comment: String value to connectionDidFinishLoading but [self.connectionDidFinishLoading:myURL]; myURL is NSURLConnection

Comment: myURL is a variable "name" that stores an instance of NSURLConnection

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in many way.

1.You call this webservice from

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

1. You save the data in

   -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection

and this checking can done in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
if ([getDealsDec isEqualToString:passingDealDec]){
}
```

Comment: if it works then you acept this answer and upvote it

Comment: i placed [self viewDidload]; in didSelectRowAtIndexPath so Total page recall i thing it's not good so Please Help me any other way to call

Comment: then use the second approch